# Error code 100 fitting gamma3 distribution using fitdist in r (paramlist error)

Tags: r

I am trying to fit multiple distributions of my data, to find the best fit, with fitdistr from library(fitdistrplus). I use dgamma3 from library(FAdist). How can I set the start parameter for each distribution?

```
library(FAdist)
library(fitdistrplus)
x <- rnorm(30,5,1)
fitdist(x, distr = 'gamma3',start = list(meanlog=0,sdlog=1))
```

Here is the error:

```
$start.arg
$start.arg$meanlog
[1] 0

$start.arg$sdlog
[1] 1


$fix.arg
NULL

Error in checkparamlist(arg_startfix$start.arg, arg_startfix$fix.arg,  : 
  'start' must specify names which are arguments to 'distr'.
```

Modified on 2021/7/15:
I change the parameter list, still got error.
I am using library: FAdist, fitdistrplus

```
x <- rgamma3(30, shape = 1, scale = 1, thres = 0)
fitdist(x, distr = 'gamma3', start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1, thres = 0)) 

[1] "gamma3"
$start.arg
$start.arg$shape
[1] 1

$start.arg$scale
[1] 1

$start.arg$thres
[1] 0


$fix.arg
NULL
Error in checkparamlist(arg_startfix$start.arg, arg_startfix$fix.arg, : 'start' must specify names which are arguments to 'distr'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list of initial parameters (start) needs to have names corresponding to the dgamma3 function. From the documentation:

```
dgamma3(x,shape=1,scale=1,thres=0,log=FALSE)
```

So,

```
fitdist(x, 'gamma3', start=list(shape=1,scale=1, thres=0))
```

Comment: I still got error asking for paramlist  

> fitdist(x, distr = 'gamma3', start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1, thres = 0))
Error in checkparamlist(arg_startfix$start.arg, arg_startfix$fix.arg,  : 
  'start' must specify names which are arguments to 'distr'.